# Changing third level nodes in proc report using proc documents

Tags: sas, report, tableofcontents

I am trying to make a customize labels in proc report using proc documents. Basically i want the table to have just one level of headers

I move the proc report table out under the `Dir` and then relabel the table. But even after that, the TOC still have a subnode.

Here is my MWE

```
/*proc greplay nofs igout=work.gseg; */
/*   delete _all_;                   */
/*run;                               */
/*quit;                              */

ods listing close;
ods pdf file="before.pdf" contents=yes  ;
ods document name=test(write);

title1 'Using Proc REPORT';
title2 'Simple Report';
* Simple report;

proc report data=test nofs;
 columns  name sex age;
 define name / display;
 define sex / display;
 define age / display;
 run;

ods document close;
ods pdf close;


proc document name=test;
   list / levels=all details; run;
   /*-- Move output from under folders --*/
   move \Report#1\Report#1\Report#1 to ^;run;
   /*-- Verify document leaf nodes moved out from under the folders --*/
   list / levels=all details; run;
   setlabel \Work.test\Report#2 "Custom Heading"; run;
   /*-- Delete folders --*/
   delete \Report#1/* , \Report#2 */; run;
   /*-- Verify folders were deleted --*/
   list / levels=all details; run;
   /*-- Close Listing Destination --*/
   ods listing close;
   /*-- Replay output (Print and GPlot to PDF) --*/
   ods pdf file="after.pdf"  contents=yes ;
      replay; 
      run;
   ods pdf close;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `proc document` looks fine for me. The point is you need to move all higher level objects to first level.

But you will still get the `Table *` marks in your TOC introduced by `proc report`.

To remove those marks, first add option `contents=""` in your `proc report`, which removes the higher level TOC contents. This is necessary no matter what types of ods destination you want, either rtf or pdf.

```
proc report data=test nofs contents="";
    columns  name sex age;
    define name / display;
    define sex / display;
    define age / display;
    break before name / contents="" page;
run;
```

Then you need `pdftoc=1` for your `ods pdf` statement, which limits your TOC to first level.

```
proc document name=test;
    ods pdf file="after.pdf" pdftoc=1 contents=on;
        replay; 
        run;
    ods pdf close;
run;
quit;
```

If you output to rtf, you do not need `pdftoc=1` in the 2nd step for ods output, simply like:

```
proc document name=test;
    ods rtf file="after.rtf" toc_data contents=yes;
       replay; 
       run;
    ods rtf close;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: It been a while since i looked at this. But it seems that your solution removes the entire toc. I still want to see the title in the toc.